# Regex to add digit between delimiter characters if missing

Tags: java, regex

I didn't use regex a lot and I need a little bit of help. I have a situation where I have digits which are separated with dot char, something like this:

```
0.0.1
1.1.12.1
20.3.4.00.1
```

Now I would like to ensure that each number between `.` has two digits:

```
00.00.01
01.01.12.01
20.03.04.00.01
```

How can I accomplish that? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Do you want to accept empty strings? What about just one number like `1` or `11`?

Comment: "between `.` has two digits" implies the values on the ends do not need to have 2 digits (eg "1.3.1" becomes "1.03.1" because only "3" was between `.`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `String.split()` to accomplish this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] splitString = "20.3.4.00.1".split("\\.");
    String output = "";
    for(String a : splitString)
    {
        if(a.length() < 2)
        {
            a = "0" + a;
        }
        output += a + ".";
    }
    output = output.substring(0, output.length() - 1);
    System.out.println(output);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use this pattern

```
\b(?=\d(?:\.|$))
```

and replace with `0`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/259)

```
\b              # <word boundary>
(?=             # Look-Ahead
  \d            # <digit 0-9>
  (?:           # Non Capturing Group
    \.          # "."
    |           # OR
    $           # End of string/line
  )             # End of Non Capturing Group
)               # End of Look-Ahead
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the matching groups retrieved from matching the following expression: `/([^.]+)/g`.

### Example:

```
public class StackOverFlow {

    public static String text;
    public static String pattern;

    static {
        text = "20.3.4.00.1";
        pattern = "([^.]+)";
    }

    public static String appendLeadingZero(String text) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(text);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while (m.find()) {
            String firstMatchingGroup = m.group(1);

            if (firstMatchingGroup.length() < 2) {
                sb.append("0" + firstMatchingGroup);
            } else {
                sb.append(firstMatchingGroup);
            }

            sb.append(".");
        }

        return sb.substring(0, sb.length() - 1);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(appendLeadingZero(text));
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am going with the assumption that you want to ensure every integer is at least two digits, both between `.` and on the ends.  This is what I came up with

```
public String ensureTwoDigits(String original){
    return original.replaceAll("(?<!\\d)(\\d)(?!\\d)","0$1");
}
```

Test case

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Foo f = new Foo();
    List<String> values = Arrays.asList("1",
          "1.1",
          "01.1",
          "01.01.1.1",
          "01.2.01",
          "01.01.01");
    values.forEach(s -> System.out.println(s + " -> " + f.ensureTwoDigits(s)));
}
```

Test output

```
1 -> 01
1.1 -> 01.01
01.1 -> 01.01
01.01.1.1 -> 01.01.01.01
01.2.01 -> 01.02.01
01.01.01 -> 01.01.01
```

The regex `(?<!\\d)(\\d)(?!\\d)` uses both negative lookbehind and negative lookahead to check if a single digit has other digits around it.  Otherwise, it will put a zero in front of every single digit.  The replacement string `"0$1"` says put a `0` in front of the first capturing group.  There really is only one, that being `(\\d)` -- the single digit occurrance.

EDIT:  I should note that I realize this is not a strict match to the original requirements.  It won't matter what you use between single digits -- letters, various punctuation, et. al., will all return just fine with zero in front of any single digit.  If you want it to fail or skip strings that may contain characters other than digits and `.`, the regex would need to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this simple regex:

```
\\b\\d\\b
```

and replace with `0$0`